# Is there a way to get an automated email with the report of an Azure Monitor Log query

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitoring

Is there a possible way to get any automated way, say any integration of other Azure services are also fine - to get a downloaded report or something throught an email
Say my log output looks like this, I want this to run everyday at a certain time and email me the results in a tabular form or something
[Sample Lof query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9seH.png)

I havent got an idea regarding what to do, I can download it as an excel file, but I need some automated way of getting it in my mail as a report or something

Comment: Have you tried any procedure so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Logic apps for automation. Create a logic app with consumption plan.

You use **"Schedule"** connector's for **"Recurrence"** of the action automatically. You can add additional parameters to run at specific time.

[image]

[image]

From **"Azure Monitor Logs"** select **"Run query and list results"**.

[image]

Select **"Resource Type"**. I have selected `Application Insights` here. you can select as per your requirement where you want to run your KQL Query.

[image]

Sample log query
[image]

[image]

Select ** "Create HTML table"**. Next Action select **"Compose"**.

[image]

Compose is used for styling the HTML table for sending in the mail

`Compose`:

```
<style>
Table {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

Table td, Table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px 4px;
}

Table th {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4fb2f2;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

Select **"Send an Email v2"**:
First `Outputs` value is from **"Compose"** and second `Output` is from **"Create HTML table"**:

[image]

**`Result:`**
You will get an email with the table in ascending order on timestamp.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain the html part, not able to find that in trigger

Comment: not able to get that operation

Comment: Create HTML table is an action inside Data Operation . [image](https://i.imgur.com/0YLP8rl.png)