# Custom message Azure Alerts

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

Custom message logs azure

I'm doing centralized monitoring, my idea was to send all the logs from my 40 data factories to a log workspace, and every time it fails, I'll be alerted, but does this have a chance of going wrong? Another question, I'm having difficulty customizing the error messages, I can't get RunError type information from the activity. Would you help me

Answer (score 0):

> but does this have a chance of going wrong?

No there is no chance of going wrong, whenever  a new log entry comes based on alert conditions it will alert.

> I'm having difficulty customizing the error messages

You can use Azure Logic apps for customizing messages
In logic apps you can send in email body your customized message too.
For Logging you can use below Connector in Logic app:

[image]

This action should be inside Condition in Logic apps, You can use recurrence trigger as first action to check for alerts per particular time and then send email after this adx condition is true.

For further refer this [SO-Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77193703/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-automated-email-with-the-report-of-an-azure-monitor-log/77195869#77195869) and  [SO-thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76930317/how-can-i-include-the-trace-message-that-triggered-an-azure-appinsights-alert-in/77012864#77012864).